# Another phrase for 'Here I was'

Tags: phrases, synonyms

In conversation, we often say *Here I was*, followed by *A*, and *B*, and then something like, *but ....* used in contrast.   This form of expression does not seem to translate well to the written word.

- Am I mistaken?
- Are there other ways to describe this phenomenon that when something happens, an atypical situation occurred?

Comment: The written word is often relaying stories in past tense, so "There I was in the middle of nowhere staring at a lion who was staring back at me. I was in trouble but I was completely alone."

Comment: Something like this springs into mind as also common in speech: Here I was thinking of how I could let her down without breaking her heart, but it turns out she was interested in the other J.R. the whole time!

Comment: To try to help think about devices or phrasing to achieve something like this in writing, I think I'd need more information about the kind of writing, register, target readership, and what you hope to effect. Some specific attempts and questions about how well it achieves some purpose and a request for alternatives seems like it would be the most productive strategy.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: See also [writers.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, there are countless ways to say that. I would come up with:

> - **"There I was..."**
> - **"It was right then that..."**
> - **"At that very moment I..."**

"There I was, in a foreign country and having just been robbed of all my money and credit cards."

"It was right then that this stranger stopped and asked me whether..."

"At that very moment I heard an explosion."